# Compare the Definitions of Two Tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Is there a way to compare programmatically in T-SQL the definitions of two tables.

Not only the column names and the data types, but all definitions that are returned by:

```
sp_help 'table_name'
```

Comment: There are plenty of tools to do this, and some can even deploy the changes . Why not use an existing tool out there?

Comment: My goal is to unify tables among multiple databases. For that I will need the differences and then to generate a script that will "fill" the other tables with the missing definitions.
If there is a tool, I am happy to use it. Thank you.

Comment: Then I'd suggest getting one of those tools. A search will give you a wealth of options.

Comment: i use visual studio sql schema compare and data compare, i think the free edition contains these as well, it's pretty good

Comment: If tables in two databases have `ZIP Char(5)` and `ZIP Int` what is the "missing definition"? How do you "fill" a new non-null column? Do indexes and triggers matter?

Comment: HABO, it will be great if we can catch column type differences as well. That is why I was looking in my question for a way to compare. E.g. "Compare Table1 Table2 - Result: Identical or Different".

Answer (score 2):

I would say best practice is to install Visual Studio, make a database project, import a source database into it, and then compare target databases to the database project. (All in Visual Studio)

Then you can also put the database project in source control if you want.

It uses the Sql Server Schema compare. Using that alone could also be a solution.

Answer (score 1):

The following example may be part of the solution for you. It returns any rows where there is a mismatch between the two tables on any of the attributes shown in the result. As others have mentioned, there are specialist tools used to compare database objects in a much more sophisticated way.

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set ('SELECT * FROM tbl1',NULL,NULL)
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set ('SELECT * FROM tbl2',NULL,NULL);
```